# JSONField, Django, PostgreSQL, retrieving data

Tags: django, postgresql, django-jsonfield

I have a JSONField which seems to be successfully storing a JSON as a string in my database.

How do I retrieve this data as a dictionary?

```
class Package:
    node = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)

packageInstance = Package.objects.get(id=packageId)
print(packageInstance.node)
```

Comment: What makes you think it isn't already one?

Answer (score 2):

Your `packageInstance.node` is a python dictionary already

The official docs verify it too https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Simply put Django converts the json string to python dict automatically when you work with JSONField like you showed.